# Timeout problem on IIS call to API from .Net 6 application

Tags: iis, .net-6.0

We have an application that call a web api.

From Visual studio/postam from our local computers it works fine.
From server with IIS we get a timeout on call. Postman calls from that same server works fine, so it is not a route problem or network misconfiguration.

Any idea on that? We configured any timeout in the call, so, everything is ISS default confiuration.

From the the application point of vue, it is a post async call. And, again, it works from local dev.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64977 .NET 6 has rich logging support that you can utilize to see into such issues. Note that there are fundamental differences when web apps running on VS and IIS, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 So, never assume things can be that simple.

Comment: You can try to increase request timeout in IIS to slove this issue: In IIS Manager, right click on the site and go to Manage Web Site -> Advanced Settings. Under Connection Limits option, you should see Connection Time-out.

Comment: thank you. I added the class and we will see if we get more data.
Timeout was set to 2mn and same problem

Comment: Can you post the full error message? what is the difference between the two servers?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. We had to get ip proxy address, and once done, it works.

Thanks for your help